# How can I upload a file from my local machine to a Jupyter notebook on Kaggle and run it there?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, conv-neural-network, kaggle

I am trying to install a library on Kaggle runtime, but I get an error that says "metadata-generation-failed". What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Here is the code that I used to install the library on google colab (Worked fine):

```
!pip install google-colab 

from google.colab import files

    
uploaded = files.upload()
 
for fn in uploaded.keys():
    new_path = fn
    img = image.load_img(new_path, target_size=(250, 250))

    img_plot = plt.imshow(img)
    x = image.img_to_array(img)
    x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
    images = np.vstack([x])
    predict_class = model.predict(images, batch_size=4)
    predict_class = np.argmax(predict_class)
    print(classes[predict_class])
```

Answer (score 0):

On the kernel creation page, you'll see an option to upload a dataset. Click on the "Upload dataset" button. You can upload the your file there and when you are running jupyter notebook on kaggle, use the kaggle api/package to download the file.
https://www.kaggle.com/docs/api

Answer (score 0):

```
#This should work

!pip install kaggle

from google.colab import files
files.upload() #run this and upload your key

!mkdir -p ~/.kaggle
!cp kaggle.json ~/.kaggle/
!chmod 600 ~/.kaggle/kaggle.json

!kaggle datasets download -d [author_name]/[dataset_name]
!unzip [dataset_name].zip

path = "/content/[file_name]"
```